# Export XLS throwing error in Saiku

Tags: pentaho, export-to-excel, saiku

After running the query in Saiku, I gave Export xls. It throws error msg like "Sorry. We really did try. Something went wrong. Please try again or contact your administrator.".

Other exports csv,pdf working fine.

Pls see the attached screens.